# Validate if input value is 1,000,000.00 or more

Tags: jquery, string, validation, numbers

I am using a priceFormat plugin that automatically place commas and decimals on the input field, so when a user types in 1000000 it displays it as 1,000,000.00. What I want to do is create some type of validation that will trigger if the value provided by the user is 1,000,000.00 or more.

This is what I have:

```
$('input#amount').priceFormat( {limit: 12} ).bind().blur( function() {

  if( $('#amount').val() >= 1000000){                       

    // pop up notification                          

});
```

It will not validate because I'm guessing the input value contain a string instead of numbers?

Answer (score 4):

Try `parseInt` -

```
if( parseInt($('#amount').val().replace(/,/g,""),10) >= 1000000){
```

As Kato rightly points out, you'll also need to remove any commas in the string before passing it to `parseInt`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: This will only parse up to the first comma?

Comment: @Kato The `g` modifier on the regex should cause it to remove all commas.

Answer (score 2):

```
if( parseInt($('#amount').val.replace(/[^0-9.]/g', '')) >= 1000000 ) { ... }
```

You may also wish to utilize a hidden field to store the actual value and to validate it; this way your formatted value isn't delivered to the server (they could put other characters that are actually invalid in there as well).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to parsing it as an int you will need to convert it back to a normal number by removing the , commas.

```
 if(parseInt($("#amount").val().replace(/[,$]/g, ""),10)) > 1000000){
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap `parseInt` or `parseFloat` around the value:

```
if (parseInt($("#amount").val()) >= 1000000){
    //validated
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's because `.val()` is a string. You should be using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace the `,` with nothing, and then parse it, otherwise it will be split on the comma and use the values before that, so other wise it will be `1` instead of `1000000`.

So:

```
if (parseInt($("#amount").val().replace(/,/g, "")) >= 1000000){
//validated
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript comparison will work with strings and numbers, for example these are valid though confusing.

```
"10" > 1  ==> true
"10" > 11 ==> false
"10000" > 10 ==> true
"10 000" > 10 ==> false
```

But your problem is dots and commas in the formatted string. Parse them away so its converted to number correctly.

```
if(  $('#amount').val().match(/([0-9,]+)/)[0].replace(/, /g,'') > 1E6 ) {
  ...
```

This converts string e.g. "10,000.00" to "10000" and compares it against 1000 000.